# Minify particular files with Vite on Laravel

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-livewire

I'm building a Laravel app and have 4 .js files bundled with Vite.

Here is vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/sass/style.scss',
                
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/clipboard.js',
                'resources/js/list.js',
                'resources/js/filter.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

When I run `npm run build` app.js and clipboard.js are built and minified correctly however list.js and filter.js exist in /public/build/assets directory but remain empty.

If I change the contents of list.js to the contents of clipboard.js then list.js is built just fine with the contents in it minified therefore the problem is with the original contents of list.js file. But I don't have any idea what's wrong with it because it works fine and have no errors in it.

list.js original code:

```
function articlesList(favourites, route)
{
    return {
        favourites: favourites,
        favourite: function (id) {
            const data = {
                item_id: id
            };

            axios
                .post(route, data)
                .then((r) => {
                    const id = r.data.id;
                    const action = r.data.action;

                    if (action === 'remove') {
                        let favourites = [];
                        for (const key in this.favourites) {
                            if (this.favourites[key] !== id) {
                                favourites.push(this.favourites[key]);
                            }
                        }

                        this.favourites = favourites;
                    } else if (action === 'add') {
                        this.favourites.push(id);
                    }
                }).catch((e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        }
    };
}
```

But the main issue is that I don't want list.js and filter.js files to be minified. I just need it to be added to manifest.json file so it could be updated correctly on users devices. Maybe the described issues are connected. How do I do it in Vite?